# Automatically parse logs fields with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Let's say I have this kind of log :

> Jun  2 00:00:00 192.168.14.4 date=2016-06-01 time=23:56:05
>   devname=POPB-FW-01 devid=FG1K2D3I14800220 logid=1059028704 type=utm
>   subtype=app-ctrl eventtype=app-ctrl-all level=information vd="root"
>   appid=40568 user="" srcip=10.20.4.35 srcport=52438
>   srcintf="VRF-PUBLIC" dstip=125.209.230.238 dstport=443 dstintf="OUT"
>   proto=6 service="HTTPS" sessionid=424666004 applist="Monitor-all"
>   appcat="Web.Others" app="HTTPS.BROWSER" action=pass
>   hostname="lcs.naver.com" url="/" msg="Web.Others: HTTPS.BROWSER,"
>   apprisk=medium

So with this code below, I can regex the timestamp and the ip in future elastic fields :

```
filter {
    grok {
    match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{client}" }
    }
}
```

Now, how do I automatically get fields for the rest of the log ? Is there a simple way to say :

The thing before the "=" is the field name and the thing after is the value.

So I can obtain a JSON for elastic index with many fields for each log line :

> {
>
> ```
>     "path" => "C:/Users/yoyo/Documents/yuyu/temp.txt",
>     "@timestamp" => 2017-11-29T10:50:18.947Z,
>     "@version" => "1",
>     "client" => "192.168.14.4",
>     "timestamp" => "Jun  2 00:00:00",
>     "date" => "2016-06-01",
>     "time" => "23:56:05",
>     "devname" => "POPB-FW-01 ",
>     "devid" => "FG1K2D3I14800220",
>     etc,...
> ```
>
> }

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I am really dumb

It was easy, rather than search on google, how to match equals, I just had to search key value matching with logstash.

So I just have to write :

```
filter {
   kv {
   }
}
```

And it's done !

Sorry